# How to call generic overloaded method in C#

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

Not very familiar with C# and generics so I may be missing something obvious, but:

Given:

```
public interface IA { }

public interface IB
{  void DoIt( IA x );
}

public class Foo<T> : IB where T : IA
{
    public void DoIt( IA x )
    {  DoIt(x); // Want to call DoIt( T y ) here
    }

    void DoIt( T y )
    {  // Implementation
    }
}
```

1) Why doesn't the method `void DoIt(T y)` satisfy the `DoIt` method implementation required by interface `IB`?

2) How can I call `DoIt(T y)` from within `DoIt( IA x )`?

Comment: Hmm for me I don't see a reason do restrict T like that, because the `DoIt` implementation of IB actually only accepts `IA`'s as argument, so why to restrict it again? Just a useless level of indirection for my point of view.

Comment: @ckruczek: this can be useful, when descendants of `Foo<T>` must perform some `T` specific actions, and all of them should be stored in the same container (e.g., collection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Because any `T` *is* `IA` (this is given from contraint), but not every  `IA` *is* `T`:

```
class A : IA {}
class B : IA {}

var foo_b = new Foo<B>();
var a = new A();

// from the point of IB.DoIt(IA), this is legal;
// from the point of Foo<B>.DoIt(B y), passed argument is not B
foo_b.DoIt(a);
```

2) If you are sure, that `x` is `T`, then use cast:

```
public void DoIt( IA x )
{  
    DoIt((T)x);
}
```

if `x` can be anything, and `DoIt(T)` can be optional, use `as`:

```
public void DoIt( IA x )
{  
    DoIt(x as T);
}

void DoIt( T y )
{
    if (y == null)
        return;

    // do it
}
```

Otherwise you can throw exception or consider another approach, depending on particular use case.